# in 2D dimensional plane, is it problematic to have Frenet-Serret frame with zero curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, frenet-frame

I have a Frenet-Serret frame moving on a 2-D plane. As of now, I do not care about the binormal vector. So my equations are given by,

\begin{align}
\dot{T} = v\kappa N \\
\dot{N} = -v\kappa T
\end{align}

Here $v$ is the constant speed and $\kappa$ is the curvature. I don't see any problem with these equations if $\kappa = 0$, but I have read that the frame is not defined if curvature is zero.

Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the curve is regular (has nonzero velocity at each point) you can always define a right-handed $T,N$ frame everywhere. But you must allow curvature to change sign. (Ordinarily, we always define $\kappa\ge 0$.)

Comment: By regular, does it also mean there is no corner on the curve?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you allow only piecewise-smooth curves, you don't have a Frenet frame at the corners.

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in [my free differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will go through the book.